# Replacing text using add_filter

Tags: filters, hooks

I'm trying to replace "More Details" text from the below functions using an **add_filter** hook

```
function awsm_job_more_details( $link, $view ) {
        $more_dtls_link = sprintf( '<div class="awsm-job-more-container"><%1$s class="awsm-job-more"%3$s>%2$s <span></span></%1$s></div>', ( $view === 'grid' ) ? 'span' : 'a', esc_html__( 'More Details', 'wp-job-openings' ), ( $view === 'grid' ) ? '' : ' href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '"' );
        echo apply_filters( 'awsm_jobs_listing_details_link', $more_dtls_link, $view );
    }
```

What I tried.....

```
function example_callback( $more_dtls_link, $view ) {
    $more_dtls_link = sprintf( '<div class="awsm-job-more-container"><%1$s class="awsm-job-more"%3$s>%2$s <span></span></%1$s></div>', ( $view === 'grid' ) ? 'span' : 'a', esc_html__( 'Hello World', 'wp-job-openings' ), ( $view === 'grid' ) ? '' : ' href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '"' );
    return $more_dtls_link;
}
add_filter( 'awsm_jobs_listing_details_link', 'example_callback',10, 2);
```

Text is getting replaced to "Hello World" but the link is broken on the Button. May I know what I'm missing here??

Comment: did you check your PHP error log? Your new function uses `$link` but there is no `$link` variable. Also the filter does not pass the original `$link` URL, it passes the HTML, so it doesn't work the way you thought it did. You can't copy paste the function and modify it to what you want, you'd need to do a search/replace of the HTML in `$more_dtls_link` instead. Where does `awsm_job_more_details` come from?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just managed to fix it using string replacement function in php.

```
function replace_btn_text( $more_dtls_link, $view ) {
    $link = htmlspecialchars($more_dtls_link);
    $str = str_replace('More Details', 'View Details', $link);
    $new_link = htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
    return $new_link;
}
add_filter( 'awsm_jobs_listing_details_link', 'replace_btn_text',10, 2);
```

Suggest me if I need to do any improvements here..